# How to apply sort by ascending order for datetime in every group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-analysis

I have a data set to be grouped according to `'user_id'` and `'contest_id'` and among that, I have to sort every user in each contest who have entered the contest on basis of date and time in ascending order.

I have tried first grouping the data according to `contest_id` and `user handle` then I tried sorting the dates in ascending order using sort_values after converting the `datetime` column into `to_datetime'

When i am trying to save the code it gives an error 
'''

```
      Excel doesn't support timezones in datetimes. Set the tzinfo in the 

       datetime/time object to None or use the 'remove_timezone' Workbook() 

       option
```

'''

```py
       dftotal.groupby(["contestID", "userHandle"])

       dftotal["registerDateTime"]=pd.to_datetime(dftotal.registerDateTime)

       dftotal["RegistrationDateTime"] = dftotal["registerDateTime"]

       dftotal["submitDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(dftotal.submitDateTime)

       dftotal["SubmissionDateTime"] = dftotal["submitDateTime"]

       dftotal = dftotal.sort_values(by=['RegistrationDateTime'])
```

**data is**

```
        contest_id user_id  registration    submission          score 
        1234       abc     2012-01-09       2012-01-09           90
                          21:51:00+00:00   22:51:00+00:00 


        4489      pabc     2013-01-09     2013-01-09             39
                         21:51:00+00:00   22:55:00+00:00 

        1234     tiop      2012-01-09      2012-01-09            100
                        23:51:00+00:00   23:55:00+00:00 

        4489    pabceu    2013-01-09      2013-01-09              39
                        23:20:00+00:00   23:55:00+00:00
```

**expected is**

```
        contest_id user_id   registration     submission             score 
        1234       abc      2012-01-09       2012-01-09              90
                         21:51:00+00:00   22:51:00+00:00 

        1234      tiop    2012-01-09       2012-01-09               100
                        23:51:00+00:00    23:55:00+00:00 

        4489      pabc    2013-01-09      2013-01-09                 39
                        21:51:00+00:00   22:55:00+00:00 

        4489     pabceu   2013-01-09     2013-01-09                  39
                        23:20:00+00:00  23:55:00+00:00
```

Comment: You say you sorted by contest_id, the variable is contestID without the underscore, or is the variable just contest based on what the data output says.  Mabey a typo is what I am saying :)

Comment: I am sorry it is a typo! i will edit it thanks. If you can pleas help me solivng this

Comment: Sure, I've never used Pandas, but I'm guessing to edit the last line to be  dftotal = dftotal.sort_values(by=['contestID'])

Comment: Highlight, select the columns with the datatime zones and convert them to text format.  It is explained [here](https://excel.tips.net/T002680_Converting_From_Numbers_to_Text.html) then you should be able to save the excel document.

Comment: The column names in the code and in the data are different. The error is raised by code that is not shown. Being a recent contributor is not a valid excuse. You should read (again?) [ask] and ensure that your data can be easily copy and pasted into a dataframe (with `read_clipboard`). Currently it is not because the timestamps are on 2 different lines. And you should show the line that tries to save the data and raises the error.

Comment: I understand but i hope you understand it was difficult to copy the datetime properly and align the column name according to it, it always used a different line for that. iIjust want a little hint on how to solve

Comment: And I have put the code that gives the error i.e to_datetime part gives me the error

Answer (score 0):

I finally could reproduce and fix.

#### Steps to reproduce

```
import pandas as pd
import io

t = '''contest_id  user_id  registration    submission          score 
        1234       abc     2012-01-09 21:51:00+00:00       2012-01-09 22:51:00+00:00           90
        4489      pabc     2013-01-09 21:51:00+00:00     2013-01-09 22:55:00+00:00             39
        1234     tiop      2012-01-09 23:51:00+00:00      2012-01-09 23:55:00+00:00            100
        4489    pabceu    2013-01-09 23:20:00+00:00      2013-01-09 23:55:00+00:00              39'''

dftotal=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=r'\s\s+', engine='python')

print(dftotal.to_string())

dftotal['registration'] = pd.to_datetime(dftotal.registration, utc=True)
dftotal['submission'] = pd.to_datetime(dftotal.submission, utc=True)

print(dftotal.to_string())
dftotal.to_excel('contest_new.xlsx')
```

Which displays:

```
   contest_id user_id               registration                 submission  score
0        1234     abc  2012-01-09 21:51:00+00:00  2012-01-09 22:51:00+00:00     90
1        4489    pabc  2013-01-09 21:51:00+00:00  2013-01-09 22:55:00+00:00     39
2        1234    tiop  2012-01-09 23:51:00+00:00  2012-01-09 23:55:00+00:00    100
3        4489  pabceu  2013-01-09 23:20:00+00:00  2013-01-09 23:55:00+00:00     39
   contest_id user_id              registration                submission  score
0        1234     abc 2012-01-09 21:51:00+00:00 2012-01-09 22:51:00+00:00     90
2        1234    tiop 2012-01-09 23:51:00+00:00 2012-01-09 23:55:00+00:00    100
1        4489    pabc 2013-01-09 21:51:00+00:00 2013-01-09 22:55:00+00:00     39
3        4489  pabceu 2013-01-09 23:20:00+00:00 2013-01-09 23:55:00+00:00     39
```

and raises:

> TypeError: Excel doesn't support timezones in datetimes. Set the tzinfo in the datetime/time object to None or use the 'remove_timezone' Workbook() option

#### Possible fixes:

1. Use openpyxl:

   This error is raised by the xlsxwriter backend. If openpyxl is installed it is enough to ask for that engine:

   ```
   ...
   dftotal.to_excel('contest_new.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
   ```

   It automatically removes the tz information and correctly writes to the excel file
2. Explicitely remove the ts information:

   the timezone information can be explicitely removed with `tz_localize(None)`:

   ```
   ...
   dftotal['registration'] = pd.to_datetime(dftotal.registration).dt.tz_localize(None)
   dftotal['submission'] = pd.to_datetime(dftotal.submission).dt.tz_localize(None)
   dftotal = dftotal.sort_values(by=['registration'])
   print(dftotal.to_string())

   dftotal.to_excel('contest_new.xlsx')
   ```

   The dataframe displays as:

   ```
      contest_id user_id        registration          submission  score
   0        1234     abc 2012-01-09 21:51:00 2012-01-09 22:51:00     90
   2        1234    tiop 2012-01-09 23:51:00 2012-01-09 23:55:00    100
   1        4489    pabc 2013-01-09 21:51:00 2013-01-09 22:55:00     39
   3        4489  pabceu 2013-01-09 23:20:00 2013-01-09 23:55:00     39
   ```

   and is written without error by the default xlsxwriter engine.

Comment: This is definitely not an answer. It is only presented as, to show a new user how to build a [mcve]. It is intended to be deleted after OP's feedback.

Comment: '''                                                                                                                           
        df= pd.read_excel(io.StringIO("contestRegistrations.xlsx"), sep=r'\s\s+', 
                                                                                                                   
       engine = 'python')   '''  got an error saying **Unknown engine: python**

Comment: @shibangibarua: you could at least show syntactically correct code ;-). I have almost guessed that the error was raised at the time you try to write the dataframe in a Excel sheet. And that is exactely what I have already asked: please show the line raising the error. It is probably `df.to_excel(...)` but what parameters do you use?

Comment: I am quite new to python and this platform in general. I didn't understand what exactly you meant by that also the line that is raising the error is `dftotal.to_excel ("Contest_new.xlsx")`

Comment: @shibangibarua: do you know whether you use openpyxl or xlsxwriter?

Comment: @shibangibarua: I finally could reproduce and fix. See my edit. BTW, you should remove [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56790976/3545273)

Comment: It still doesn't work first of all this line isn't working at all `dftotal=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=r'\s\s+', engine='python')`  what is t supposed to be? The file is excel so when i change the code to this `dftotal=pd.read_excel(io.StringIO('contestRegistrations.xlsx'), sep=r'\s\s+', engine='python')` it doesn't work and throws me an error saying unknown engine python

Comment: @shibangibarua You are kidding, aren't you. `t` is defined just above! (`t='''...'''`)

Comment: @shibangibarua: I have not **your** Excel file on **my** system. I have used a memory file defined with a string to simulate a csv file and initialize a dataframe. Your question contains a mix of `ContestID` and `contest_id` so I choosed one and built a dummy dataframe to be able to reproduce the problem. If you had given a [mcve], I would have used **your** data...

Comment: I am sorry to annoy you so much my actual file has too many columns that i cannot insert here and it takes a long time to format to be proper. The thing about 't' i was asking is when i run it in my system to read a file it gives me error  unknown engine python. I understood you created a dummy dataframe. should i post a link to actual files here? actually there are three files that are supposed to be merged together using two keys so you can imagine the number of columns i have to deal with.

Comment: Also when i used my old code to write the file to excel and used  'openpyxl' it crashed conda,  it closed automatically and that is happening everytime so i don't know what to do

Comment: @shibangibarua I'm pretty sure we are not that far.. The crash is probably caused by openpyxl not being installed on your system. Have you tried to remove the timezone info with `tz_localize(None)` (the second way in my post)?

Comment: yes!  i did try tz.localise(none) and i installed openpyxl as well, I don't know where am i going wrong with this.

Comment: As per the [mcve] what you should have done is to extract a small number of rows and columns from your files, just enough to reproduce the problem and post here the (small) files in csv format with the actual column names. And again just enough code to raise the error. Thats what is called a [mcve] ;-)

Comment: @shibangibarua: Oops I have written that too early... Just be be sure, what are your Python and pandas versions, in case it matters. And what happens if you run my unmodified code? (of course don't overwrite your real excel file!)

Comment: `dftotal["registerDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(dftotal.registerDateTime, utc = 
        True).dt.tz_localize(None)`

        `dftotal["submitDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(dftotal.submitDateTime, utc = 
        True).dt.tz_localize(None)`                                                                                              
        `dftotal.to_excel('contest_new.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')`

Comment: @shibangibarua: do not use `engine=openpyxl` if you use `tz_localize(None)`

Comment: Okay, now i get this new error `IOPub data rate exceeded.`
`The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output`
`to the client in order to avoid crashing it.`
`To change this limit, set the config variable`
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

`Current values:`
`NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)`
`NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)`

Comment: @shibangibarua: I am sorry but I do not use jupyter notebook so I cannot help you there. You'd better ask a new question.